# Is there a control or view in OSX dev like "All My Files" in Finder?

Tags: macos, cocoa, finder

I want to implement a view like the "All My Files" view in Finder:

[image]
There are sections, like "PDF Documents", "Music", and "Movies".

I cannot find which control this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as such, but if you can require Mavericks, you may find NSStackView helpful.

It's not properly documented yet, but [the release notes describe it](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000741-CH2-SW14).

(Note to residents of the future year 2014 or 2015: Please update the above link to go to the AppKit Older Release Notes, once all the Mavericks stuff gets moved over there after OS X 10.10 comes out.)

Comment: +1 [InfoBarStackView](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/InfoBarStackView/Introduction/Intro.html) (Demonstrates how to use NSStackView, to show how to stack arbitrary views together.)